# Best approach to sending messages using tcpip without blocking Listener

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I currently have a .NET console app which connect to 4 Clients of which only 1 at anytime will send information to my listener.

This currently works correctly but there is a new requirement to send a message (basically a custom connection check) to each client every 30 seconds and if no response is received within 15 seconds, retry again up to 5 times - therefore if it fails 5 times, we raise an alarm.

While I have this partially implemented in terms of sending the messages and capturing the response in the listener, I am unsure if my approach is correct as this is all been managed within the 1 thread.

I am worried that this frequent activity of of sending the messages and managing the responses etc will block or impact the listener in terms of receiving other messages.

Does anyone have a suggest as to what the best implementation to follow for a scenario like this?

Thanks

From the Main method, I am invoking the server connections, listener and elapsed events:

```
ServerConnectionMgr.InitializeConnectionTimer();
ServerConnectionMgr.ConnectServers();
ListeningMgr.StartListener();
```

Below is the InitializeConnectionTimer which create a timer event to trigger the connection message every 30 seconds.

```
    public static void InitializeConnectionTimer()
    {
        int Interval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Interval"]);
        Timer mTimer = new Timer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Interval).TotalMilliseconds,
            Enabled = true
        };
        mTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SendToServerElasped);
    }

    private static void SendToServerElasped(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _clientSocket1.ClientSocket.Client.Send(_Buffer, 0, 
            _Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            _clientSocket1.ConnectionCheck.SentDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            _logger.Error("SocketException: {0}", se);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
        }

    }
```

This is my Listener Method

```
public static void ClientListener()
    {
        TcpListener clientListener = null;
        try
        {
            clientListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8887);
            // Start listening for client requests.
            clientListener.Start();
            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;
            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {
                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                TcpClient client = clientListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                data = null;
                bool isDataAvailable = false;
                // Get a stream object for reading
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                int iLoop;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (!isDataAvailable)
                    {
                        isDataAvailable = stream.DataAvailable;
                        if (clientListener.Pending())
                        {
                            _logger.Debug("Client listener is pending");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isDataAvailable)
                    {
                        // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                        iLoop = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, iLoop);
                        isDataAvailable = false;
                        data = Helpers.RemoveUniCodeChars(data);
                        if (data.Substring(0, 3) == "123")
                        {
                            //do the normal operations that this app was designed for.
                        }
                        if (data.Substring(0, 3) == "ABC")
                        {
                            //How best to manage this response?
                        }
                    }

                    if (clientListener.Pending())
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            _logger.Error("SocketException: {0}", se);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            _logger.Info("Stop listening for new clients.");
            clientListener.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add some code, so we can judge the situation, please.

Comment: Rookie mistake :) Code examples added

Comment: I really do not understand how this is supposed to work. You await client connections. As soon as they are idle, you close them. At the same time, you want to check if they are still alive periodically? I'd expect a lot of NullReferenceExceptions and/or IOExceptions. How are you supposed to send on a closed socket? And how do you expect a client to respond to a message, it cannot receive?

Comment: Now another question would be, what do you want to test in the first place. If a specific TCP connection is alive and kicking or if a _client_ is generally running and reachable?

Comment: Best way is to create a list of sockets so you can periodically check for activity.  So See MSDN example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example).  1)  Look at the state object.  Add properties to state so you can check activity. 2) In the AcceptTcpClient( method every time a new client connects you create a state object.  You also can add the state object to a List<StateObject> which you timer event can use to check activity of each connection.  So I would add to state object a DateTime when last message was received.

Comment: Now, if clients are supposed to try and connect to you within X time, I'd make note of the last time, they sent something. Then have a watchdog check if one of those dates is longer ago than X * n... You don't need an extra message for that. If they were able to send you productive data, they obviously were connected.

Comment: @Fildor - Thanks for the replies, the closing of the socket is a mistake. The check is more client is generally running and reachable

Comment: @ jdweng - Thanks for the link, it looks like i may need to rethink the implementation of this

Comment: _" The check is more client is generally running and reachable"_ Then you maybe want to separate the status check from productive data. I guess I would use some kind of UDP ping/pong system to check on clients' status indedependently from what's going on on TCP.